# Python cannot use the List in tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I want to sum the int in my list. I create a global list. But if I want to sum my list it is no entry in it. Although I fill it with for example [1,3,4]. I use python 3.x and tkinter.

```
listEN = []

class Waterentry:

    def __init__(self, master, list=[]):
        global listEN
        self.txtDisplay = Entry(self.frame, bd=20, insertwidth=1, font=30)
        self.txtDisplay.pack(side=TOP)

        self.frame2 = Frame(master)
        self.frame2.pack(side=TOP)

        self.BN_txtOk = Button(self.frame2, text='OK', command=lambda: self.txtOk(self.txtDisplay, listEN))
        self.BN_txtOk.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.frame3 = Frame(master)
        self.frame3.pack(side=TOP)
        self.BN_water= Button(self.frame3, text='100ml', command=lambda: self.addNumber(100,listEN))
        self.BN_water.pack(side=LEFT)

    def txtOk(self, EN_number, listEN):
        EN_number = self.txtDisplay.get()
        listEN.append(int(EN_number))
        print(listEN)
        return listEN

    def addNumber(self, BN_number, listEN): 
        listEN.append(BN_number)
        print(listEN)
        return listEN 

root1 = Tk()
waterentry = Waterentry(root1)
print(sum(listEN))
root1.mainloop()
```

I always get a blank entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print after the mainloop (as shown below):

```
root1.mainloop ()
print (sum (listEN))
```

Comment: thank you very much i always write it for the mainloop.